# Change docker starting options

Tags: docker

I am Ubuntu 16.04 user. `Docker` version is `17.03.1-ce`.
I want to modify `DOCKER_OPTS`, so I tried to modify `/etc/default/docker` and `/etc/init.d/docker` adding `DOCKER_OPTS="-H 127.0.0.1:2375"`.

But it doesn't make a sense. After `sudo service docker restart` I have no change:

```
CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           ├─15521 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://
           └─15530 docker-containerd -l unix:///var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock --metrics-interval=0 --start-timeou
```

How modify `DOCKER_OPTS` properly?

Comment: what you're doing works if you install docker as packaged by canonical.  if from upstream docker then read on https://docs.docker.com/v1.11/engine/admin/systemd/#custom-docker-daemon-options

Comment: systemctl may need reload. do "systemctl restart docker" and check it